# Calcular porcentagem de determinadas cores em uma imagem

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, histograma

Estou com um programa que lê uma imagem e verifica se há determinadas cores naquela imagem, se sim pinta cada pixel de uma cor determinada. Eu não consegui achar materiais na internet que possa me ajudar, apenas essa [página](https://coredump.pt/questions/43167867/color-percentage-in-image-python-opencv-using-histogram) que possui uma solução usando histogramas, porém não compreendi como isso é feito mesmo com o código disponibilizado. É realmente possível utilizar histogramas? Existe alguma outra forma mais fácil de calcular a porcentagem de cores da imagem? *Eu tentei usar uma regra de três pra poder calcular mas retorna valores absurdos.*

Trecho de código:

```
img = cv2.imread("IF23-1-2018.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, imgThresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
somenteAsfalto = cv2.inRange(img, asfaltoMax, asfaltoMin)
somenteTerra = cv2.inRange(img, terraMax, terraMin)
somenteVerde = cv2.inRange(img, verdeMax, verdeMin)

for i in range(0, altura):
    for j in range(0, largura):
        if somenteAsfalto[i,j] == imgThresh[i,j]:
            #pinta de vermelho onde tem asfalto
            img[i,j] = vermelho
            contAsfalto += 1
        if somenteTerra[i,j] == imgThresh[i,j]:
            #pinta de amarelo onde tem terra
            img[i,j] = amarelo
            contTerra += 1
        if somenteVerde[i,j] == imgThresh[i,j]:
            #pinta de violeta onde tem verde
            img[i,j] = violeta
            contVerde += 1
        if imgThresh[i,j] == 1 and imgThresh[i,j] == 0:
            img[i,j] = verde
            cont += 1
        if imgThresh[i,j] != somenteTerra[i,j]:
            img[i,j] = verdeCons

contNatural = contVerde + contTerra
contConstruido = contAsfalto + construido
porcVerde = (100*contVerde)/qntPixels
porcConst = (100*construido)/qntPixels
print("Pixels de asfalto: {}\nPixels de Terra: {}\nPixels onde tem verde: {}".format(contAsfalto, contTerra, contVerde))
print("Tamanho da imagem: {}".format(qntPixels))
print("Contador construido: {}\nContador contVerde: {}".format(construido, contVerde))
print("Porcentagem construída: {}%\nPorcentagem verde: {}%".format(porcConst, porcVerde))
print("DEU RUIM nº {}".format(cont))
```

[image: Imagem de entrada]

Imagem de entrada

[image: Imagem de saída]

Imagem de saída

Comment: Como vc definiu as cores do asfalto do teto, teria como achar algo meio marrom claro?

Comment: utilizei um programa de manipulação de imagens para pegar as cores (em RGB) mínima e máxima do objeto que quero identificar

Comment: entendi, programa pago?

Comment: Não, eu utilizei o Gimp, que é gratuito. Segue o site oficial dele: https://www.gimp.org/

Comment: Fechou, valeu irmão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Contar Pixels

Como a função `inRange()` é utilizada, os pixels podem ser contados com a função `countNonZero()`.

Então a quantidade de pixels obtido em cada `inRange` podem ser obtidos da seguinte forma:

```
pixelsAsfalto = cv2.countNonZero(somenteAsfalto)
pixelsTerra = cv2.countNonZero(somenteTerra)
pixelsVerde = cv2.countNonZero(somenteVerde)
```

E a quantidade total de pixels da imagem:

```
pixelsTotal = img.size
```

Ao dividir cada quantidade de pixels pela quantidade total, você obtém a porcentagem.

#### Código

Então o código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mostrar_inRange(img, mask):
    imask = mask > 0
    sliced = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
    sliced[imask] = img[imask]
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.imshow(sliced)
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

img = cv2.imread("IF23-1-2018.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, imgThresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

somenteAsfalto = cv2.inRange(img, asfaltoMax, asfaltoMin)
somenteTerra = cv2.inRange(img, terraMax, terraMin)
somenteVerde = cv2.inRange(img, verdeMax, verdeMin)

pixelsAsfalto = cv2.countNonZero(somenteAsfalto)
pixelsTerra = cv2.countNonZero(somenteTerra)
pixelsVerde = cv2.countNonZero(somenteVerde)

pixelsTotal = img.size

mostrar_inRange(img, somenteAsfalto)
mostrar_inRange(img, somenteTerra)
mostrar_inRange(img, somenteVerde)

print('% Asfalto: ', (pixelsAsfalto/pixelsTotal)*100)
print('% Terra: ', (pixelsTerra /pixelsTotal)*100)
print('% Verde: ', (pixelsVerde/pixelsTotal)*100)
```

> **Observação:** A segmentação de cores em escala de cinza não é a melhor opção, como a imagem é colorida o melhor seria realizar isto no espaço de cores HSV. Mas a qualidade da imagem também não é das melhores e a cor do asfalto é muito similar ao telhado das casas... Então a segmentação deve ser refinada de outras maneiras, além da utilização da segmentação de cores. Uma alternativa para encontrar o asfalto seria limitar o intervalo de busca com a utilização de *Hough Lines*.

Comment: Ao pedir pra imprimir a porcentagem separada de Asfalto, Terra e Verde (nas três últimas linhas) imprime uma matriz pra cada

Comment: Utilizei a variável errada, o correto seriam as variáveis `pixelsVAR` e não `somenteVAR`, corrigi o código.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!