# Retornar porcentagem de marrom na imagem

Tags: python, opencv

Tenho um código em que pego um vídeo e salvo uma imagem a cada 20 frames e pego uma fatia dessa imagem, até ai consegui fazer, mas preciso analisar se possuem pixeis com tom igual ou mais escuro de marrom que esse: RGB 194, 187, 138 e não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, como detectar porcentagem da cor marrom com esse RGB especifico?

Esse é meu código até agora

```
import cv2 
import os
import numpy as np

# Read the video from specified path 
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("D:/outpy.avi") 

currentframe = 0
x = 20
while(True): 

    # reading from frame 
    ret,frame = cam.read() 

    if ret: 
        # if video is still left continue creating images 
        name = 'D:/' + str(currentframe) + '.png'
        print ('Creating...' + name) 

        # writing the extracted images
        if currentframe == x:
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
            imagem = cv2.imread("D:/{}.png".format(x))
            fatia = imagem[0:150, 150:300]


            x = x + 20
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        # increasing counter so that it will 
        # show how many frames are created 
        currentframe += 1
    else: 
        break

# Release all space and windows once done 
cam.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Veja se as seguintes respostas ajudam: [Calcular porcentagem de determinadas cores em uma imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354848/75104) e [Detecção de cor e dizer qual e a cor que esta aparecendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/337094/75104).  Mas se atente ao fato de que a biblioteca OpenCV trabalha no espaço de cores BGR como padrão, então se o espaço de cores RGB for utilizado, realize a conversão com `cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: Já tinha visto os dois links, mas não consegui resolver pela dica que passam neles

Comment: Você precisa primeiro definir um intervalo em algum tipo de espaço de cores, por exemplo RGB, ou o mais recomendado, o HSV. Definindo o intervalo do que você considera marrom, fica fácil verificar... Uma segestão de intervalo é a [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46113436/7690982)

Answer (score 0):

quando quero detectar % de uma certa cor em minha imagem vc faz assim:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('J9MbW.jpg')

brown = [194, 187, 138]  # RGB
diff = 20
boundaries = [([brown[2]-diff, brown[1]-diff, brown[0]-diff],
               [brown[2]+diff, brown[1]+diff, brown[0]+diff])]
# in order BGR as opencv represents images as numpy arrays in reverse order

for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype=np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    ratio_brown = cv2.countNonZero(mask)/(img.size/3)
    print('brown pixel percentage:', np.round(ratio_brown*100, 2))

    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```